# How to enable shared Clipboard for Windows and XRDP?

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

We´ve set up a development environment on Ubuntu 14.04, running in a LXC container hosted on a Proxmox 4.2 Server.

The container is connected to our AD and accessed with xrdp.

Problem:
The clipboard isn´t working. From what I understood, that´s because XRDP knows three clipboards:

- Cutbuffer
- Primary Selection
- Clipboard Selection

Windows only knows the Cutbuffer, which is deprecated in modern Linux Distributions.

One solution we found is to install autocutsel, but that didn´t solve the problem for us.

Another possible solution we found is this script found at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285. This may be the solution, but it´s too big. Installing a new server, trying and debugging the script and then hope, that it works on the original container is not an option at the moment.

We´re looking for a lean solution, maybe we overlooked something, when we installed autocutsel?

Thanks for all answer is advance.